# How to save session in Firefox?

Tags: big-sur, firefox

I am used to Ubuntu and I am new to Mac. I'm using Macbook Pro 16" 2019 with BigSur 11.2.3. What is the way to keep Firefox remember my opened tabs? I just quit Firefox with red dot on the left, then I run it again and it opens empty (without my tabs). Of course I configured Firefox to save session.

Answer (score 5):

**The red dot is not Quit.**

This is the first big thing you need to learn about Macs. The red dot closes the window, it does not quit the app. [Some single-pane apps will auto-quit on close - System Prefs etc, but this is not the rule for document-based apps].

if you want any app to remember its last session - which *all* well-behaved apps do these days - then if you want to quit, use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd>  [or Quit from the application menu].

This applies to within one session, or through reboot/shutdown/boot too. All Apple apps will return to the last-used state, even if there were unsaved documents.

Closing a window, with the red dot or any other method, removes that window from the 'last session' information & breaks your workflow.

Some browsers may have a 'get out of jail free' card. In the History menu will be a 'restore all windows from last session' or similar wording - don't rely on it, but sometimes that will pull back windows you had manually closed. There may also be a 'recently closed' item &/or 're-open last tab' which might let you step back tab by tab to get your closed pages back.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126941/discussion-on-answer-by-tetsujin-how-to-save-session-in-firefox).